# How to make a node to rotate around a point(CGPoint) in a spritekit game project

Tags: rotation, sprite-kit

As we know, the default rotate action is rotating around the center point of the node, but how to make it rotate around a appointed or specific point?

Comment: Add your node to another SKNode at an offset. Change zRotation of the parent. What happens is that your node rotates around its parent at the given offset (which defines the radius of the rotation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use actions, I make everything a function of an internal time in my game, it makes everything consistent and for more complex games it's crucial.

This is from a space based game I did where planets would rotate around a point.

**Explanation:**

- direction: 1 or -1 (clockwise or counterclockwise)
- _model.orbitSpeed: the speed of the movement around the central point
- _model.initialAngleInRadians: the starting point of the orbit (since it's a function of time)
- _model.orbitDistance: how far away from the center the object is moving
- time: an integer representing time (in most of my games this is equivalent to frames, since I used a fixed timestep model always)

  self.position = CGPointMake(cos(direction*(((float)time*_model.orbitSpeed)+_model.initialAngleRadians))*_model.orbitDistance, sin(direction*(((float)time*_model.orbitSpeed)+_model.initialAngleRadians))*_model.orbitDistance);

Obviously you will need to update all moving objects with the current time for ever frame, I do this in the update method. This is fairly straight forward.

You can boil it down to: self.position = CGPointMake(cos((float)time)*distanceFromCenter,sin((float)time)*distanceFromCenter);

Comment: This can be done much easier by adding the rotated node to another node, and change the parent node's zRotation.

Comment: Yes, but then you loose control over the zRotation of the child itself, that would then go on to rotate. Or you need to hack it in as a counter rotation. 

I also like the code better when doing it through pure math instead of using rotation of children. In larger projects I personally like simplicity of the code. But it's a matter of taste.